# Python getparent() not working

Tags: python, xml

I'd like to use getparent() in some code I'm working on to read XML files.  When I try what's below I get this error:  `AttributeError: getparent`

I assume I'm making a basic mistake but after an hour of searching and trial and error, I can't figure out what it is.  (Using python 2.7 if that matters)

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree
url = [file.xml]
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=url)

txt = 'texthere'

for elem in tree.iter(tag='text'):
    print elem.text
    print elem.getparent()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Element` objects created with the standard library module [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) do not have a `getparent()` method. `Element` objects created with [lxml](http://lxml.de) do have this method. You import lxml (`import lxml.etree`) in your code but you don't use it.

Here is a small working demonstration:

```
from lxml import etree

XML = """
<root>
  <a>
    <b>foo</b>
  </a>
</root>"""  

tree = etree.fromstring(XML)

for elem in tree.iter(tag="b"):
    print "text:", elem.text
    print "parent:", elem.getparent()
```

Output:

```
text: foo
parent: <Element a at 0x27a6f08>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better to try this. There is some problem with your import libraries. same thing can done usng DOM. great example in here. http://www.mkyong.com/python/python-read-xml-file-dom-example/